# Transform multiple XML files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have 2 XML files that I need to transform into 1 based on matching.  The primary file (Assets.xml) looks like this

```
<Records>
  <Record>
    <Field id="15072">Server A</Field>
    <Field id="15073">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="65502">Information</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Field>
    <Field id="15083">
      <Reference id="205773">Control Instance A</Reference>
    </Field>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Field id="15072">Server B</Field>
    <Field id="15073">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="65502">Physical</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Field>
    <Field id="15083">
      <Reference id="205773">Control Instance A</Reference>
    </Field>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

The second file (ControlDefinitions.xml) looks like this

```
<Records>
  <Record>
    <Field id="15056">AR005</Field>
    <Field id="15086">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="65504">Information</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Field>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Field id="15056">AR001</Field>
    <Field id="15086">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="65504">Information</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Field>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Field id="15056">AR002</Field>
    <Field id="15086">
      <ListValues>
        <ListValue id="65504">Physical</ListValue>
      </ListValues>
    </Field>
  </Record>
</Records>
```

For the output, I need to create a single record for each Asset/Control Definition combination that have the same Type (i.e. Information, Physical, etc.).  The output should look something like this.

```
<InstanceRecords>
  <InstanceRecord>
    <Asset>Server A</Asset>
    <ControlInstance>Control Instance A</ControlInstance>
    <ControlDefinition>AR005</ControlDefinition>
  </InstanceRecord>
  <InstanceRecord>
    <Asset>Server A</Asset>
    <ControlInstance>Control Instance A</ControlInstance>
    <ControlDefinition>AR002</ControlDefinition>
  </InstanceRecord>
</InstanceRecords>
```

The stylesheet I have been using is below.  Is there any way to do this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="control_definitions" select="document('../XML/ControlDefinitions.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template name="getAsset">
      <xsl:value-of select="Field[@id='15072']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getISMSInstance">
      <xsl:value-of select="Field[@id='15083']/Reference"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getControlDef">
      <xsl:for-each select="$control_definitions/Records/Record">
        <xsl:if test="Field[@id='15086']/ListValues/ListValue='Information'">
          <ControlDefinition>
            <xsl:value-of select="$control_definitions/Records/Record/Field[@id='15056']"/>
              </ControlDefinition>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Records">
      <InstanceRecords>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record">
          <xsl:if test="Field[@id='15073']/ListValues/ListValue='Information'">
            <InstanceRecord>
              <Asset>
                <xsl:call-template name="getAsset"/>
              </Asset>
              <ControlInstance>
                <xsl:call-template name="getInstance"/>
              </ControlInstance>
              <xsl:call-template name="getControlDef"/>
            </InstanceRecord>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </InstanceRecords>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks!  This worked great for matching the ListValues, but didn't quite meet the desired output.  Below is the output I am trying to generate.  Is that possible?  Thanks!

```
<InstanceRecords>
  <InstanceRecord>
    <Asset>Server A</Asset>
    <ControlInstance>Control Instance A</ControlInstance>
    <ControlDefinition>AR005</ControlDefinition>
  </InstanceRecord>
  <InstanceRecord>
    <Asset>Server A</Asset>
    <ControlInstance>Control Instance A</ControlInstance>
    <ControlDefinition>AR001</ControlDefinition>
  </InstanceRecord>
  <InstanceRecord>
    <Asset>Server B</Asset>
    <ControlInstance>Control Instance A</ControlInstance>
    <ControlDefinition>AR002</ControlDefinition>
  </InstanceRecord>
</InstanceRecords>
```

Comment: your ControlDefinitions.xml seems to be invalid as they have multiple ids that are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template that matches **Records** rather than specifically testing for "Information" you could pass the actual **ListValue** as a parameter to your named template

```
   <xsl:call-template name="getControlDef">
       <xsl:with-param name="type" select="Field[@id='15073']/ListValues/ListValue" />
   </xsl:call-template>
```

Actually, because ultimately you want an **InstanceRecord** element generated for each record, it will help if you pass in the "asset" and "instance" values as parameters too

```
  <xsl:call-template name="getControlDef">
    <xsl:with-param name="instance"><xsl:call-template name="getInstance"/></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="asset"><xsl:call-template name="getAsset"/></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="type" select="Field[@id='15073']/ListValues/ListValue" />
   </xsl:call-template>
```

Then in the **getControlDef** template, you would test it like this

```
<xsl:template name="getControlDef">
  <xsl:param name="type" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$control_definitions/Records/Record">
    <xsl:if test="Field[@id='15086']/ListValues/ListValue=$type">
```

Or, better still, add the condition to the **xsl:for-each**

```
<xsl:template name="getControlDef">
  <xsl:param name="type" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$control_definitions/Records/Record[Field[@id='15086']/ListValues/ListValue=$type]">
```

And in the for-each loop, you would then output your **InstanceRecord**, like so...

```
    <InstanceRecord>
      <Asset>
        <xsl:value-of select="$asset" />
      </Asset>
```

... And so on for the other fields.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="control_definitions" select="document('../XML/ControlDefinitions.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template name="getAsset">
      <xsl:value-of select="Field[@id='15072']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getInstance">
      <xsl:value-of select="Field[@id='15083']/Reference"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getControlDef">
      <xsl:param name="type" />
      <xsl:param name="asset" />
      <xsl:param name="instance" />
      <xsl:for-each select="$control_definitions/Records/Record[Field[@id='15086']/ListValues/ListValue=$type]">
        <InstanceRecord>
          <Asset>
            <xsl:value-of select="$asset" />
          </Asset>
          <ControlInstance>
            <xsl:value-of select="$instance" />
          </ControlInstance>
          <ControlDefinition>
            <xsl:value-of select="Field[@id='15056']"/>
          </ControlDefinition>
        </InstanceRecord>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Records">
      <InstanceRecords>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record">
          <xsl:call-template name="getControlDef">
            <xsl:with-param name="instance"><xsl:call-template name="getInstance"/></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="asset"><xsl:call-template name="getAsset"/></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="type" select="Field[@id='15073']/ListValues/ListValue" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </InstanceRecords>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please comment that this didn't match your requirements and edit the required output into the question instead - it's more part of the question than the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @user3571408 I've rolled back my answer to what it was previously. As explained by "Rup" above, the correct response would be to leave a comment to explain why it didn't quite work and add your actual required output to the original question. (It's shouldn't be too hard for me to correct my XSLT, by the way).

Comment: Sorry about that, wasn't sure where to respond.  I have added the desired output to my original post.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: @user3571408 I've now amended my answer, and I think the output should match now.